# Anime set in present day Japan with people gaining powers and a powerful main bad guy who can make things float

Tags: story-identification, anime

Takes place in present day Japan (not feudal age).  Basic premise is that some dude secretly released these…ability particles or orbs or something, into the air and random people got powers.

It starts off with the main character (currently powerless) working as, I think, a bike delivery guy or something. He goes into, I think, a diner or something.  He is narrating & talking about how rough the city is and how it’s kicked his ass. A guy with the power to move fast swooshes in and steals everyone's wallets. Despite not having powers, he is still able to see the guy because he’s just that damn cool, I guess.  He chases the guy down and confronts him. Not sure what happens after that but I know he ends up standing in a clearing or on top of a building with three other dudes, who have powers, and they are surrounded by Japanese special forces in helicopters. The big dude in the group tells him to book and they will handle it.

The MC ends up getting powers somehow and then hooks up with these other people with powers. The main chick is the daughter of some high-up bad dude. This other chick is like an abused captive that was sent in to spy on the good guys.  In one scene, the main chick is fighting this other really strong chick on this floating thing, maybe a ship or plane, and the super-powerful main bad dude is making it float with his super-cool powers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this a movie or a series?

Comment: Do you know which approximate decade this was from. 80s, 90s, 2000s, and whether it was hand drawn or computer animated?

Comment: Is it possible that this was one of the animated adaptions of the X-Men. The villain sounds a lot like Magneto. I believe that there were 2 or 3 Anime versions of the X-Men. If not, did it seem like it was trying to be the X-Men or did it have a completely different style\feel.